# Как сделать крестик для очистки инпута как у гугла?

Tags: html, javascript

Подскажите скрипт, но не jquery.

Comment: Почему не хотите использовать библиотеку JQuery ?

Comment: А зачем?

Comment: Потому, что она много весит, а мой сайт должен загружаться как можно быстрее

Comment: подгружай минифицированный файл, к тому же браузер кэширует js файлы, и проблем у тебя не будет ;)

Comment: Ядро jQuery весит чуть менее, чем 100 Кб, о чём разговор? Если на странице картинки занимают 200 Кб, то jQuery уже каг бе не при чём вообще...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<script>
function prev(x){do{x=x.previousSibling;}while(x&&x.nodeType==3)return x;}
function next(x){do{x=x.nextSibling;}while(x&&x.nodeType==3)return x;}
function showClose(v){
    if(v.value.length){
        next(v).style.display = '';
    }
    else{
        next(v).style.display = 'none';
    }
}
</script>
<input type="text" onkeyup="showClose(this)">
<b class="close" style="display:none" onclick="var el=prev(this);el.value='';showClose(el);">X</b><br />
<input type="text" onkeyup="showClose(this)">
<b class="close" style="display:none" onclick="var el=prev(this);el.value='';showClose(el);">X</b>
```

Стилизацию и поиск крестика сделайте на свой вкус. В данном скрипте крестик ищется как следующий после инпута элемент.

Comment: Спасибо, как раз то, что нужно

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно понимаю надо форму очистить.
Используйте:

```
<button type=reset>
```

для этого даже javascript не нужен.

Answer (score 1):

Очистить один инпут можно просто `inputElement.value = ""` в обработчике `onclick` 
 этого крестика.